# Automatic creation of lists

Tags: python

I would like to create a code where I could create (n) numbers of lists automatically without creating them one by one. 
I tried this example, where I wanted to get five lists named "my_list" automatically where every list has assigned ten numbers from 0 to 9 (for example).

```
for i in range(1,6):
    ("my_list_"+str(i)) = []
    for j in range(10):
        ("my_list_"+str(i)).append(j)
```

The message is: "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"

This is just an example, the real problem is how to get the lists automatically without creating them one by one. Is possible to do this in Python? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is that, you are trying to assign a list to a string. You cannot do that.
If you need to create a lot of lists, first create another single list to store them all. Like this:

```
my_lists = []
for i in range(1,6):
    new_list = []
    for j in range(10):
        new_list.append(j)
    my_lists.append(new_list)
```

If you don't like this and want to reach these lists from a global scope using a variable name like `my_list_3`, you can try a little trick like this:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    globals()["my_list_"+str(i)] = []
    for j in range(10):
        globals()["my_list_"+str(i)].append(j)

print my_list_3
```

This will print `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: The second way was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome but the second way is not very common and I doubt that it is considered good programming. If you are doing a serious job, I highly recommend you to get used to the first way.

Comment: The problem is that after I have to use the lists calling them by name. For example, I have to print "my_list_2" or for every element in "my_list_1" I have to multiply them by 2. What I wanted to find was a way to create lists automatically and then use them calling them by name.

Comment: You don't need to call them by name. For example, if you want to use **my_list_1**, you could use **my_lists[1]** instead (in the first code) =)

Answer (score 1):

The normal, regular way to handle this sort of requirement is to keep the keyed lists in a dictionary, not as variable names with a suffix.

```
my_list=dict()
for i in range(1,6):
    my_list[i] = []
    for j in range(10):
        my_list[i].append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a list of lists using a list comprehensions:

```
my_lists = [range(10) for _ in xrange(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a function:

```
>>> auto_list = lambda n: [[] for _ in range(n)]
>>> auto_list(10)
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

If you wish for every list to be generated with *say* random numbers:

```
from random import randint


def auto_list(n):
    return [[randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(n)]


print auto_list(10)
```

Returns:

```
[[86, 33, 82, 28, 20],
 [13, 89, 22, 8, 73],
 [83, 44, 58, 71, 21],
 [66, 54, 41, 24, 8],
 [74, 98, 89, 53, 40],
 [63, 83, 13, 72, 68],
 [51, 55, 61, 36, 34],
 [38, 72, 95, 58, 82],
 [80, 16, 10, 44, 22],
 [9, 65, 84, 14, 91]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 40
my_lists = []


for i in range(1,40):
    my_lists.append([])

for list in my_lists:
    list.append(3)
```